# In Google Firebase, what customizations can I set for google authentication beyond languageCode and addScope?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

In [firebase documentation here,](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin?authuser=0) it shows an example of `firebase.auth().languageCode` and `firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider().addScope`, but I do not see any other list of valid authentication options.

I would like to change the app display name on the popup ("Choose an account to continue to WXYZ app") where WXYZ is custom instead of the firebase default.

Answer (score 2):

To customize the OAuth domain, you need to follow the following instructions:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#customizing-the-redirect-domain-for-google-sign-in

You can't customize the OAuth domain name from the client side API. This is an important security mechanism that explains to the user what app they are granting consent to for the requested scopes.